# SELECT within an anchor

Tags: html, css, list, select

I have a curtain-list with links to some local html-files. As of late, I learned that you should not have SELECT within an anchor. I read that you could make this happen in the CSS instead, but no more info than that.

```css
HTML:
     <div id="button9">
      <ul style="float:right;">
       <li><a href="#"><strong> <!--rullgardin i första knappen-->
  <SELECT ONCHANGE="window.location=this.value">
        <OPTiON>            Projekt</OPTiON>
  <OPTiON VALUE="internetshistoria.html">Internets Historia </OPTiON>
  <OPTiON VALUE="netiquette.html">     Etik & Integritet </OPTiON>
  <OPTiON VALUE="webbtekniker.html">     Webbtekniker </OPTiON>
  </SELECT></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="presentation.html"> Vem är jag? </a></li>
    <li><a href="kontaktamig.html"> Kontakta mig </a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

Sorry for the swedish words in the content :P

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of the anchor? Since it doesn't go anywhere it shouldn't be a link at all. It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I believe that just removing the anchor should do it. But you wont be able to style the select box to look like an anchor. In this case I would just create a dropdown list instead like a menu with normal anchor links within them.

Comment: I am trying to keep my 3 buttons + my dropdown list in the top-right and to be able to validate it without faults. Right now the validator is telling me that I can´t have SELECT within an anchor.